# System Upgrade: 2.3.0 -> 2.3.1 -> Cron errors

Tags: error, upgrade, cron

I really hope someone can help. As my name suggests I am a noob to Magento. I installed Magento a few months ago and have been going through training and learning sites to find my feet. Yesterday, an update was released (v2.3.1). I have tried to update it via the SYSTEM UPGRADE option. At first, I had errors that the cron was not set up or configured correctly - to fix this I did the following:

- Putty into server
- log in as owner
- changed to root
- ran the command  (water is the owner)
- inserted the following lines

> - - - - - /usr/local/bin/php /public_html/bin/magento cron:run |
>             grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >>
>             /public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
>   - - - - - /usr/local/bin/php /public_html/update/cron.php >> /public_html/var/log/update.cron.log
>   - - - - - /usr/local/bin/php /public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log

- exited the editor
- `crontab -u water -l`
- `bin/magento cron:run`

This gave the output of

> Ran jobs by schedule

However, the readiness check still gave the error that the cron was incorrectly configured. I tried to restart the cron service but it did not help.

I then decided to try the following:
- `bin/magento cron:remove`
- `php bin/magento cron:install` (without the [--force])

This change the cron to the following:

```
> #~ MAGENTO START d548577901e562a035b1312551f1a47d SHELL="/bin/bash"
>     * /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/water/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs
> by schedule" >> /home/water/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
> 
> SHELL="/bin/bash"
>     * /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/water/public_html/update/cron.php >>
> /home/water/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log
> 
> SHELL="/bin/bash"
>     * /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/water/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >>
> /home/water/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

-`bin/magento cron:run`

Everything seems to be working as the logs were being generated.

I tried the readiness check again - success the cron was working. BUT, how the error is

> Found non-writable path(s): /home/water/public_html/.user.ini (this
>   file I can't find on the system)
>   /home/water/public_html/generated/code/* (there are a whole bunch of
>   folders and files) /home/water/public_html/var/.htaccess (this file I
>   can't find on the system).

The permissions are set to 0644 for files and 0775 for folders.

Any ideas on how I go about fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: Update: 

I noticed that the owners of the files and folders were not correct. I corrected these by running a chown on the entire home/water/public_html/. 

I then made sure permissions were set correctly using the follow command

cd /home/water/public_html/ && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento

Comment: New problem: after the update
Problem is now showing 

Found non-writable path(s):
/home/water/public_html/.user.ini
/home/water/public_html/var/.htaccess

Problem is that these files do no exist in those folders.

Comment: replaced files from magento.zip.